# How to access json_decode parameters in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

So, i'm trying to access some input fields in a form which I get with

```
$data = json_encode($app->request->getBody());
```

It returns something like this after an echo $data:

```
"groupname=group13&description=description"
```

But I just can't figure out how to access those parameters, I've tried with

```
$data[0]
$data['groupname']
$data->groupname
```

How can I access to this array elements?

---

[UPDATE]
Tried all of your solutions, none of them worked for me :(
I've finally solved it using this since I only have 2 fields

```
$groupname = $app->request->post('groupname');
$description = $app->request->post('description');
```

Comment: Is the request issued as a GET or POST request. It looks very much like a GET request which would be a string rather than an array

Comment: It's a POST method, i'm developing an API and i get this SLIM error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: So why don't you just use `$_POST`?

Comment: You have `json_encode()` in your question, is it a typo?

Answer (score 4):

That is not JSON, it's URL encoded text... Use [`parse_str()`](https://php.net/parse_str) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, in this case if you really need to manage this final query string you can do:

```
$my_query = "groupname=group13&description=description";
```

explode elements into a assoc array using parse_str:

```
parse_str($my_query, $output);
```

var_dump of $output :

```
array(2) {
    'groupname' =>
        string(7) "group13"
    'description' =>
        string(11) "description"
}
```

you can remount your query string too using http_build_query:

```
var_dump(http_build_query($output));
string(41) "groupname=group13&description=description"
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you executed the serialize() method in jQuery

When you do a `json_encode()`, the output is like `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`